# Суть yield и return

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, return, yield

Объясните, пожалуйста, различия между `yield` и `return`. Естественно, я уже понял, что `return` после выхода из функции *возвращает* все значения, в то время как `yield` работает как генератор и *генерирует* значения на ходу. Но вот чего я не понял. Есть код:

```
def enumerate(data, counter):
    n = counter
    for element in data:
        yield n, element
        n += 1
data1 = [6, 8, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3]
for num, val in enumerate(data1, 1):
    print(num, val)
```

Почему, если вместо `yield` написать `return`, выдаст ошибку:

```
"TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"
```

Ведь если различие только в том, что `return` выдает все сразу, а `yield` работает как генератор, то и ошибки не должно быть.

Comment: «return выдает все сразу» это вы где-то глупостей поначитали. Всё, что делает return — это возвращает указанный объект и завершает работу функции. Если вы напишете `return n, element` то такая функция вернёт объект `(1, 6)` и естественно пройтись таким циклом по такому кортежу не получится.

Comment: enumerate базовая функция питона. не называйте так свою.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

после `return` функция сразу завершается

в вашем примере если место `yield` поставить `return` то функция вернёт `(6, 1)` и цикл `for` попытается сделать так:

```
num, val = 6
```

Что конечно же привидет к ошибке:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Если хотите чтобы ваш код работал с `return` то он должен выглядеть так:

```
def enumerate(data, counter):
    n = counter
    list_ = []
    for element in data:
        list_.append((n, element))
        n += 1
    return list_
```

Comment: А можете тогда объяснить в чем же различия return и yield? И почему, если написать return, то пройтись циклом по кортежу не получится? На что это влияет?

Comment: @prostak, потому что функция вызывается однократно и выдаёт только 1 результат при использовании `return`, а при использовании `yield` функция как бы вызывается многократно каждый раз с места последнего `yield` - это если совсем просто объяснять, поэтому в `for` вы получаете столько выдаваемых значений, сколько нужно, а не 1

Answer (score 5):

Как только в функции появляется ключевое слово yield, она становится функцией, возвращающей генератор.

```
def foo():
  yield 1
  yield 2

gen = foo() # generator
gen.next() # 1
gen.next() # 2
```

Генераторы являются итераторами, поэтому можно пройтись по ним циклом `for in`(ну и всё остальное, что можно сделать с итераторами).

```
for i in foo():
  print(i)

# 1
# 2
```

Основным отличием генератора от функции возвращающей список является то, что генератор - это сопрограмма(coroutine, корутина), т.е. ход выполнения программы буквально останавливается в месте вызова yield и управление возвращается в вызывающую функцию до следующего вызова next.

Таким образом, мы можем, например, создавать бесконечные генераторы, выбирая из них нужно количество элементов, не опасаясь зацикливания.