# Надо вывести все значения словарей в списке

Tags: python

```
documents = [
    {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
    {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
    {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
  ]
  def lst(values):
      for value in values:
         for key in value.values():
      return key
  print(lst(documents))
```

надо найти все значения из словарей но вот не задача, если return под циклом то выводит только одно значение, а нужно все из всех словарей, тогда выношу return из под цикла и получай ошибку

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Dictionary.values()

Comment: Не понял, расшифруйте

Comment: А ничего что я начинаю только ? И мне не ясно

Comment: Это совершенно нормально, чего то не понимать. Но этот вопрос вам разжевали со всех сторон. Все методы работы со словарем вам доступны с примерами работающего кода. Теперь ваша очередь сделать усилие

Comment: Так это не словарь, а списокв котором словари и то что вы предлагаете не работает для списка, как вы не понимаете?

Comment: Примените данный метод к каждому словарю в списке. В вашем коде вы используете конструкцию `for`, то есть вы можете проитерироваться по списку и в итоге на каждой итерации у вас будет словарь, вот к нему и применяйте метод `values()`

Comment: Чтобы получить список значений, очевидно, нужно возвращать список, а вы возвращаете просто значение. Вместо этого создайте пустой список до цикла, в цикле через append добавляйте в него значения, после цикла делайте return этого списка. Вот в этом ответе на один из ваших вопросов есть такой код: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1382342/1365 , делаете аналогично, просто вносите код в функцию, result потом возвращаете через return.

Comment: Я все это понимаю и делал уже, но у меня отображает только первый словарь, а должны все.

Comment: "Я все это понимаю и делал уже" но в вопросе делаете по-другому. В ответе, на который я дал вам ссылку код отобразит все словари.

Comment: Помогло, остался вопрос в вашем коде можно выносить rerurn из под цикла , а в моём нет, можете подсказать почему. PEP 8 читаю и не нахожу ответа на свой вопрос

Comment: @ДианаТихонова у вас отступы сломаны в коде, это не вынос return из цикла. Если совсем по простому, после каждой строки, заканчивающейся двоеточием (как в строках с for, while, if, else, elif, def, class...), должна быть строка с увеличенным отступом. У вас идет строка с уменьшенным отступом, так не должно быть, из-за этого и возникает ошибка `IndentationError: expected an indented block` - это и означает, что ожидался блок с увеличенным отступом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов много как это можно реализовать, например можно использовать `yield`, чтобы возвращать значения по одному и при этом не выходить сразу из функции, как это происходит при использовании `return`. Но по полученному результату тогда нужно как-то проитерироваться, это тоже можно сделать разными способами, например, использовать `*`:

```
documents = [
    {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
    {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
    {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
  ]
def lst(values):
    for value in values:
        for key in value.values():
            yield key # <-- возвращаем значения по одному

print(*lst(documents)) # <-- разворачиваем результат в список значений через *
```

Вывод:

```
passport 2207 876234 Василий Гупкин invoice 11-2 Геннадий Покемонов insurance 10006 Аристарх Павлов
```

Чуть подробнее про различия `yield` и `return` можно почитать, например, в ответах к этому [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201600/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-yield-%D0%B8-return).

Comment: А что такое yield ??

Comment: @ДианаТихонова Ну вот тут почитайте, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201600/%d0%a1%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-yield-%d0%b8-return

Comment: ООО, так это ваще супер, буду пробовать внедрять